# React Uploading file after I leave page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I’m looking for the way to upload files after I leave page. So basically I have dropzone uploader in modal window, and when I upload file(some big sized files) and close modal window my uploaing cancels.

So expected flow is to start uploading in modal window => then I close the modal => files are still uploading with progress bar in header?
Have anybody implemented something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use React Portal. This will help you run your component outside the root and let the upload run while navigating elsewhere in your app. This is the article:

https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html